# Python Two-Dimensional Array

Tags: python

[image]

Hello! There is a key that is written vertically in 1 column “HELLO.” It is necessary to fill the letters vertically alphabetically as in the table.

The matrix should be square (**same number of rows than columns**). Can you help please.
I placed the key vertically, but I cannot horizontally write the letters of the alphabet.

```
key='HELLO'
f=[]
count = 1
A = [['' for i in key] for i in key]
for i in range(len(A)):
    A[i][0]=key[i]
for i in range(0,len(A)):
  for j in range(0,len(A[i])):
      if A[i][0]==key[i]:
            n=count+ord(key[i])
            A[j][i]=n
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to be completely clear about your inputs, expected outputs, and what you are getting in practice. This will allow the community to help you. I am afraid that the current text is very difficult to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code

```
from itertools import cycle 
from string import ascii_uppercase 
letter = cycle(ascii_uppercase)

column1 = 'HELLO'
len_other_columns = len(column1)-1
other_columns = range(len_other_columns)

for letter1 in column1: 
    while next(letter) != letter1: ... 
    print(letter1, ' '.join(next(letter) for _ in other_columns))
```

produces

```
H I J K L
E F G H I
L M N O P
L M N O P
O P Q R S
```

---

To place the result in a list of lists, or 2D array,

```
from itertools import cycle 
from string import ascii_uppercase 
letter = cycle(ascii_uppercase)

column1 = 'HELLO'
len_other_columns = len(column1)-1
other_columns = range(len_other_columns)
# Initialize the 2D array
two_d_array = [[c] for c in column1]
# similar to the previous
for sublist in two_d_array:
    while next(letter) != sl[0]: ...
    for _ in other_columns: sublist.append(next(letter))
print(two_d_array)
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to put it in a two-dimensional array?